# sql case to sum column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display the sum of amount fields based on filename column for each system.
This is the query I tried:

```
SELECT 
    col1, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN filename LIKE '0701%' THEN (r_amt) ELSE 0 END) AS CW, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN filename LIKE '0801%' THEN (r_amt) ELSE 0 END) AS MIC, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN filename LIKE '0601%' THEN (r_amt) ELSE 0 END) AS CIC, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN filename LIKE '0401%' THEN (r_amt) ELSE 0 END) AS CIC,
FROM 
    table1 
GROUP BY col1;
```

and my result is this:

[image: result]

```
Col1    CW  MIC CIC CIC_1
--------------------------
Sys1    15  20  0   0
Sys2    0   0   50  0
Sys3    0   0   0   45
Sys4    0   0   0   0
Sys5    0   0   0   0
```

Question: I don't want the cic_1 in result, instead I want the sys 3 - CIC sum displayed in 3rd col like this:

[image: desired result]

```
Col1    CW  MIC CIC
----------------------
Sys1    15  20   0
Sys2     0   0  50
Sys3     0   0  45
Sys4     0   0   0
Sys5     0   0   0
```

Comment: You can have multiple SUM() and CASE in the same expression. `SUM(A) - SUM(B)` with the A and B replaced with CASE expressions for example.

Comment: Can't follow what you mean by `sys 3 - CIC sum `.

Comment: Your query gives a syntax error.

Comment: instead of creating a sep column "cic_1" i want all cic column data under CIC

Comment: you have two columns labeled CIC  the reason you have CIC1 is because the engine will not allow you to have two columns with the same name, so it adds a 1.  But you don't want two columns in the first place, you just want it so when a multiple/different conditions are met, both are recorded in CIC column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want this:

```
SELECT 
    col1, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN filename LIKE '0701%' THEN (r_amt) ELSE 0 END) AS CW, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN filename LIKE '0801%' THEN (r_amt) ELSE 0 END) AS MIC, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN filename LIKE '0601%' THEN (r_amt) 
             WHEN filename LIKE '0401%' THEN (r_amt)
             ELSE 0 END) AS CIC
FROM 
    table1 
GROUP BY col1;
```

Or this, if it makes more sense to you:

```
SELECT 
    col1, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN filename LIKE '0701%' THEN (r_amt) ELSE 0 END) AS CW, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN filename LIKE '0801%' THEN (r_amt) ELSE 0 END) AS MIC, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN (filename LIKE '0601%' OR filename like '0401%') THEN (r_amt) ELSE 0 END) AS CIC
FROM 
    table1 
GROUP BY col1;
```